# In a python try/except how can i pass data back to the calling script

Tags: python, exception

I have a python script that gets executed from a php script.

This script sends and email and it is several orders of magnitude faster than php with swiftmailer, but i have a problem. I don't really understand much about python or charachter encoding, and sometimes an error is generated about the encoding from the MIMEText library of python. I googled and found a solution, but i still want to have the php script as a fallback in case of failure in the python script.

The problem is, in the except loop it seems i am unable to pass the data back to php before the script terminates? any ideas on what i'm doing wrong here? You can see in the except block that i say result = {type: 'failed'} then attempt to json encode it but the data doesn't get back to the php script.

```
import sys, json, os, smtplib, socket, logging
LOG_FILE='/tmp/mandrill.out'
logging.basicConfig(filename=LOG_FILE,level=logging.DEBUG)
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.header import Header
from email.utils import formataddr

try:
    data = json.loads(sys.argv[1])
    msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
    msg['Subject'] = data['subject']
    msg['From']    = formataddr((str(Header(u'Business Name', 'utf-8')), data['from']))
    msg['To']      = data['to']
    html = data['body']
    email = MIMEText(html, 'html','utf-8')
    username = 'username'
    password = 'password'
    msg.attach(email)
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.example.com', 587, socket.getfqdn(), 3)
    s.login(username, password)
    s.sendmail(msg['From'], msg['To'], msg.as_string())
    s.quit()
    result = {'type': 'success'}
    print json.dumps(result)
except:
    result = {'type': 'error'}
    logging.exception('Got exception on main handler')
    raise
    return json.dumps(result)
```

EDIT TO INCLUDE TRACEBACK

```
ERROR:root:Got exception on main handler
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/nginx/mandrill/mandrill.py", line 16, in <module>
    email = MIMEText(html, 'html')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/mime/text.py", line 30, in __init__
    self.set_payload(_text, _charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 226, in set_payload
    self.set_charset(charset)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/email/message.py", line 262, in set_charset
    self._payload = self._payload.encode(charset.output_charset)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 9580: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Sounds like you should be posting the error message so that we can tell you how to make the Python script not fail. Chances are you end up sending faulty mail which might not display correctly, or at all.

Comment: i never was able to answer this question.

Comment: FWIW, commenta you add here will pretty much only be seen by people who commented here previously.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I can see how a messy question like this could be thought to be "unlikely to help future visitors".  There is too much between the lines and some pretty awkward assumptions here.  (And again, the downvoter probably will never see your question.)

Comment: @tripleee thanks for the suggestions triplee. i will try to go back and salvage the question if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raise` causes the Python script to terminate, so it never reaches the `return`.

The next problem is that `return` can only be used inside Python to return a value to the calling function. You probably want to print the JSON string instead (but this somewhat depends on how you are calling Python from PHP, which you have not documented here).

The traceback indicates that

```
email = MIMEText(html, 'html','utf-8')
```

is not actually true; you are lacking the `'utf-8'` parameter in the code which caused the error traceback.

Comment: See update. But I'm really only restating @mhawke's answer, so maybe you should accept that instead.

Comment: that's what i was trying to figure out. for certain charachters, the email would fail, but for others it would send fine. fwiw, i copied the MimeText straight from the python docs.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `return` to return data to the PHP calling script, you'll need to `print` it as you are doing in the successful case.

Also, calling `raise` will propagate the exception up to the main part of your script, thus preventing execution of the `return json.dumps(result)` (which should be a `print`). You don't need to raise the exception again (your script will terminate anyway).

You might also (or instead) want to set a return code from the python script via `sys.exit()`, then your PHP script can check the return code to detect errors. The convention is to set a return code of 0 for success and anything else for failure.

Also, you are using a bare except clause which will catch all exceptions - what it the actual exception that you are seeing? Can you update your question with the full traceback?

Comment: i upvoted your answer because it helped me to understand my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are killing the program with sys.exit(1). 
If you want to return data back to something, I would exchange the sys.exit(1) line with

```
    return json.dumps(result)
```

Comment: ok, well will that block of code be reached if it is placed on the line following the exception being raised? how does that work exactly with python. I'll modify the code in my question so you can see what i mean